# Problems with known optimal solution

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, global-optimization

I am looking for some problems in which we know the value of optimal solution and should find just a vector of variables. For example in N-Queens problem we know the value of optimal solution (that is equal to zero). After solving a N-Queens problem we have a vector that shows the place of every queen.

So my question has two parts:

1: Is there any other problem like N-Queens that we know the value of optimal solution and we solve the problem just for finding the amount of variables?

2: Where we practically use such problems in manufacturing?